How can I resolve "Segmentation Fault" in PostgreSQL with pgbouncer?
I installed and configured pgbouncer, but when I enter the psql command, a segmentation fault error occurs.
[postgres@test:/pgdata/pg-15/data]$ psql -U [myusername] -h localhost -d pgbouncer -p 6432
Password for user [myusername]:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I can't get any specific hints from the pgbouncer.log either.
2024-06-25 16:44:01.642 KST [36557] LOG C-0xb6b740: pgbouncer/postgres@[::1]:42698 login attempt: db=pgbouncer user=[username] tls=no
2024-06-25 16:44:02.805 KST [36557] LOG C-0xb6b740: pgbouncer/postgres@[::1]:37478 login attempt: db=pgbouncer user=[username] tls=no
2024-06-25 16:44:02.895 KST [36557] LOG C-0xb6b740: pgbouncer/postgres@[::1]:37478 closing because: client unexpected eof (age=0s)

the pgbouncer.ini configuration is as follows:
[postgres@test:/pgdata/pg-15/data]$ grep -v ";" pgbouncer.ini | tr -d "\n"

[databases]
postgres = host=localhost port=5333 dbname=postgres

[users]
[pgbouncer]
logfile = /pgdata/pg-15/data/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /tmp/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /tmp
auth_type = scram-sha-256
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = [myusername]
so_reuseport = 1

and the userlist.txt is in the format "[myusername]" "SCRAM-SHA-256$ ...", and this password is the same as the value in pg_authid.rolpassword.
Could it be that I have misunderstood the concept or operation of pgbouncer, or is there something additional that needs to be done? I would appreciate any help.

No, this is a problem of your psql client.

Does psql work correctly if you point at the real server not pgbouncer?  How did you install psql?

@jjanes psql client does work fine if i don't use pgbouncer. So I thought it was a pgbouncer issue..

It could be that pgbouncer produces some unexpected message, which psql doesn't sanitize correctly.  So that would likely be a bug in each, generating a bad message and then crashing on it.  What is the version of pgbouncer and psql (pgbouncer -V, psql -V), and the OS and version?

Are all strings anonymized to "[myusername]" really the same string, or are different instances different strings?

@jjanes The os version is rocky linux 8.9, and [myusername] is actually the same string. psql version is 15.3 and  PgBouncer version is 1.22.1

I can't reproduce this on 15.3 (which I would note is out of date, missing 4 bug-fix releases) and 1.22.1.   Although I am using ubuntu not rocky.  Can you give the full output of -V for both programs, in case the extra details reveal something interesting?

Since you are connecting as the admin user to the pgbouncer database, no real connection through to the server is used, and you are just trying to talk directly to pgbouncer for monitoring purposes.  Correct?  That does suggest different code paths would come into play.  If you change the -d argument to be 'postgres' rather than 'pgbouncer', do you still get the seg fault?

The segmentation fault is coming because you are using SCRAM-SHA-256 encryption with pgbouncer. psql client gives this error when it is not able to properly decrypt the SCARM passwords mentioned in your userlist file using the auth function.
Try changing the password_encryption to md5 and reset the user credentials to use md5 encryption. Update the userlist file with the new md5 encrypted passwords and try connecting again.

This is just nonsense.  The segfault is happening in psql, not in pgbouncer. No well written production code is going to respond to an error condition by intentionally segfaulting.  It would instead respond by generating a proper error message instead.  I've dealt with plenty of SCRAM issues in pgbouncer, and it doesn't just respond with "screw it, let's just segfault".
